# All of the pictures from screenshots I saved were saved as a .txt file. How do I convert them back into images?

Tags: screenshot, image-conversion, image-formats

I go to my files and select my "Pictures" folder. I then select my "screenshots" folder. Within this folder are all my screenshots, but for some reason saved as text instead of an image, and I would like to know how to reverse this. I've tried all sorts of file converters, and nothing has worked.

Comment: Did you try to open them to have an actual look what's in those files? Did you try to open them with a graphics viewer of your choice? What format should those files have? How did you save them?

Comment: Try to change the extension to .jpg or some other picture format and see if they will open

Comment: If you try to open them in IrfanView and they have the wrong extension, IrfanView will prompt you to rename them correctly. I am not sure if this applies when the extension is TXT, but I have seen this when a JPG was named PNG and vice-versa, and also when the file had no extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to rename the .txt files to .jpg files, then open a command prompt and go to your screenshot directory. Type "rename *.txt *.jpg"

Comment: If you have >10 pictures, it would take time. If you type this command, it renames all of them with little effort?

Comment: @EricF by default file extensions are hidden in W10, you first have to go into folder options to show them, then yes it can be done that way.

Answer (score 0):

download and any free image converter from web and select all the pictures that are showing as .txt and then convert them to jpg or png .
and i dont know if you are having that issue on phone or PC, but even if it's on phone move them to PC and convert them to .jpg

Comment: You should provide an example that you know for sure will work if this is your answer since the person asking the question already stated that she has "tried all sorts of converters".

Comment: i'm working on it